# SQL Relation and Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a database that contains two tables. I have included the create_tables.sql code if this helps. I am trying to set the relationship to make the STKEY the defining key so that a query can be used to search for thr key and show what issues this student has been having. At the moment when I search using:

```
SELECT *
FROM student, student_log
WHERE 'tilbun' like student.stkey
```

It shows all the issues in the table regardless of the STKEY. I think I may have the foreign key set incorrectly. I have included the create_tables.sql here.

```
CREATE TABLE `student`
(
`STKEY` VARCHAR(10),
`first_name` VARCHAR(15),
`surname` VARCHAR(15),
`year_group` VARCHAR(4),
PRIMARY KEY (STKEY)
)
;

CREATE TABLE `student_log`
(
`issue_number` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`STKEY` VARCHAR(10),
`date_field` DATETIME,
`issue` VARCHAR(150),
PRIMARY KEY (issue_number),
INDEX (STKEY),
FOREIGN KEY (STKEY) REFERENCES student (STKEY)
)
;
```

Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Though you have correctly defined the foreign key relationship in the tables, you must still specify a join condition when performing the query. Otherwise, you'll get a cartesian product of the two tables (all rows of one times all rows of the other)

```
SELECT
  student.*,
  student_log.*
FROM student INNER JOIN student_log ON student.STKEY = student_log.STKEY
WHERE student.STKEY LIKE 'tilbun'
```

And note that rather than using an implicit join (comma-separated list of tables), I have used an explicit `INNER JOIN`, which is the preferred modern syntax.

Finally, there's little use to using a `LIKE` clause instead of `=` unless you also use wildcard characters

```
WHERE student.STKEY LIKE '%tilbun%'
```